# Full-Size Buick shudders when braking after tire change

Tags: brakes, buick

After replacing the rear brake lines on my 1965 Buick Wildcat (4-wheel drums), I took it in to have all four tires replaced.

When I dropped it off at the shop, the brakes were fine, but when I picked the car up afterward, the car now shakes when I brake.  It's a pulsing sensation at low speeds (30mph and below) but between 30 and 50 it's a very noticeable shudder and above 50 the car shakes violently.

After I got home, I discovered that the parking brake was depressed one "click" -- not enough to illuminate the idiot light and I didn't notice any drag while driving.  My suspicion is that the pedal got bumped by the tech.  I don't know whether that may have been enough to do something.

Regardless, I called the shop and they said they didn't touch the brakes at all when they did the tires.  I took it back to them, they pulled the drums and said everything looks fine.

As a footnote, when I took the car in, there were P205/70R15s on the front and P235/60R15s on the back (it's a long story).  These were replaced with P235/75R15s which was a good visual match for the H78-15 I had in the trunk.  I don't know whether the change in size could play a part.

The work was done at a chain tire-and-battery place so I know they don't work on these very often and may not know what to look at or for.  How should I go about identifying the root of the problem?

**Update**

I did some looking around last night and found that some of the weights on the inside of the wheels are smashed up against the drums:

[image: Left Front Wheel Weight]

The lug nuts *appear* to be tight and centered all the way around, but I'm wondering whether these weights are acting as shims and at least one of the wheels isn't actually seated properly.

Comment: I assume they verified the wheels were balance correctly?

Comment: They didn't say they checked the wheel balance.  If one or more of the wheels were out of balance, shouldn't that be noticeable whenever the car is moving and not just during braking?

Comment: Ah, I misinterpreted your explanation, yeah that doesn't make sense. Do you feel the vibration in the pedal or the steering wheel?

Comment: @MooseLucifer - I've never had a shop *not* balance the wheels/tires after a tire change ... I mean, it's an extra charge. I'm sure it would be on the bill of sale as such. I mean, it can cost like $20/tire, so you know the charge will be shown.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I totally agree, but some new guy could have screwed it up, or a weight could have flown off on the drive home. If a customer returns complaining of wheel wobble I imagine that's the first thing they'd double check.

Comment: @MooseLucifer - If it was a wheel weight, why would it only be happening when the brakes are applied? I think we are not seeing the forest for the trees, here, and not focussing on the real issue which has to include the brakes. I was wondering at first if the wheels weren't torqued correctly, but seeing as how they were removed and replaced, they most have done that right was well. Something really funky going on, that's for sure.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I mentioned that misinterpretation in my second comment. I was thinking the new tires exacerbated a wearing tie-rod or suspension bushing, and something about the suspension geometry only highlights it when braking, but that's a shot in the dark, that's why I asked if it's felt in the pedal or steering wheel.

Comment: @MooseLucifer - I missed that ... great catch and agree. At this point we need to start eliminating things and it sounds like you're on the right track.

Comment: @Wildcat Matt Are we sure all the lugs are tight, and that all the lugs centered properly on what is certain to be a lug-centric car?  I only mention this as one of the very few here that was alive when this car left Detroit...

Comment: I doubt a wheel balance issue.  According to the OP, it appeared after the tire change, and only happens now while braking, at multiple speeds, intensity increasing with speed.  Sounds [feels] like 1) wheel(s) not mounted correctly, or 2) drum(s) cocked/shifted/not mounted flush during wheel changeover.  What an awesome ride, BTW [sorry, OT]

Comment: @MooseLucifer - The steering wheel feel is more like vibration and the pedal feel is more like pulsation.  When the car is going above 45, you can actually see the car shaking.

Comment: @SteveRacer - I will look at the centering of the lugs.  On the one hand that feels plausible, but on the other if the wheels were taken off and put back on, they really need to be doing something incorrectly to get it wrong twice.  (PS: Fisher codes tell me it was built in KC, so I don't think it's ever been to Detroit.)  :oD

Comment: Might be a stupid question - Did you have the wheels aligned after you got the new tires? Also - another long shot - check they installed the tires in the right direction, they should be marked with 'outside' if they are bidirectional, otherwise they will indicate a rolling direction.

Comment: @MooseLucifer - The tires are (rather cheap) whitewalls so they had better be facing properly.  I did not have an alignment done because I have been told the front end already has the maximum number of shims in it and it cannot be brought any closer to alignment than it already is -- apparently the car had been in an accident long before it was mine.  The alignment is very close to correct and thankfully the slight pull is always to the right.

Comment: I'm thinking the so-so alignment combined with your wider stickier new rubber may be causing the problem. If you have access to a concrete parking garage, try driving/braking on it and listening if the tires chirp/squeal on the concrete. This would indicate that the tires are scrubbing against the ground, which would be a possible cause of the shudder.

Comment: After your edit, yeah, anything touching the brake is going to be a problem. I'm surprised the vibration only appeared when braking. Take it back to the shop and see if they have lower profile weights?

Comment: @MooseLucifer ... This is a good time to take your notes and turn them into an answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vibration after new tires are installed is not an uncommon problem, and can usually be traced back to improperly weighted wheels or poor alignment. Improperly placed wheel weights would cause a vibration that increased in severity with speed, while vibration from an alignment issue could happen under any number of conditions depending on vehicle condition, suspension geometry, what is out of alignment (Left vs right, front vs rear, toe/camber/caster angles).

In your even rarer case, the vibration during braking only was probably caused by the wheel weights contacting the outside of your brakes as pointed out in your picture. As you suspected, this may have prevented the wheels from seating properly on the hubs. Why it only vibrated under braking is beyond me.

The easiest solutions would be to find lower profile wheel weights, or install wheel spacers to move the wheels further away from the brakes. From your picture, a simple slide-on 5 or 10mm Aluminum spacer would probably do the trick, though if you go any wider I would recommend hub-centric spacers with separate lug bolts already installed, such as the ones pictured below.

[image]

On a personal note: I purchased two sets of 20mm spacers for my car (because it looks good) for ~70 USD, about half the price of the name brand spacers (H&R comes to mind). I ordered H&R as well as the cheap ones, and found the 'cheap' brand weighed exactly the same (to the hundredth of a pound), and were concentric to ± .0005" (I have access to expensive measuring equipment at my work c:).